# Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to extract data from firebase I have two fields of type digit that causes me a compatibility problem

Other character data work except the numbers

```
package fr.halas.loginhalas.Filter;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Affichage {


    public static final String FIELD_CREATOR_NAME = "CreatorName";
    public static final String FIELD_USERID = "UserID";
    public static final String FIELD_MODULE = "Module";
    public static final String FIELD_SECTION = "Section";
    public static final String FIELD_GROUPE = "Groupe";


    private String CreatorName;
    private String Module;
    private String UserID;
    private long Section;
    private long Groupe;



    public Affichage(String CreatorName,String UserID,String Module, long Section, long Groupe) {
        this.CreatorName = CreatorName;
        this.UserID = UserID;
        this.Module = Module;
        this.Section = Section;
        this.Groupe = Groupe;
    }

    public Affichage() {
        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize users
    }

    public String getCreatorName() {
        return CreatorName;
    }

    public void setCreatorName(String creatorName) {
        CreatorName = creatorName;
    }

    public String getModule() {
        return Module;
    }

    public void setModule(String module) {
        Module = module;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public long getSection() {
        return Section;
    }

    public void setSection(long section) {
        Section = section;
    }

    public long getGroupe() {
        return Groupe;
    }

    public void setGroupe(long groupe) {
        Groupe = groupe;
    }


}
```

```
  @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot, final OnAffichageSelectedListener listener) {

            final Affichage affichage = snapshot.toObject(Affichage.class); // Error is here ! 

            creator.setText(affichage.getCreatorName());
            moduleView.setText(affichage.getModule());
            groupeView.setText("Groupe: " + affichage.getGroupe());
            sectionView.setText("Section: " + affichage.getSection());
```

The error message is 
05-10 18:00:36.850 19488-19488/fr.halas.loginhalas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fr.halas.loginhalas, PID: 19488
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long (found in field 'Groupe')

Comment: @AKSW The type of ( Groupe & Section ) is Number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After having completely removed the application on my phone and restart the compilation it is launched normally without error, the application had to give invalid cached

Answer (score -2):

these two lines:

```
    groupeView.setText("Groupe: " + affichage.getGroupe());
    sectionView.setText("Section: " + affichage.getSection());
```

should be:

```
    groupeView.setText("Groupe: " + Long.toString(affichage.getGroupe());
    sectionView.setText("Section: " + Long.toString(affichage.getSection());
```

Comment: why is this necessary in Java?

Comment: .setText is looking for a string value, affichage.getGroupe() and getSection() return long values that need to be converted to a string in order for setText to work

Comment: well, Java does this automatically, this is not Python or similar. Left side is a string, right side a primitive number which will be autoboxed to the object type `Long` and then `toString()` is called automatically. Again, this is not like in Python or whatever language

Comment: Yes, this is wrong, the error is a bad parse from string to long, no long to string, yes, java does that automatically, the code would not even compile, and the error happens some lines above